# logstash create strange index name

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

i use logstash 7.9.3 and with this version i have problems to create right index name like logstash-2021.01.**01**. I need first 9 days of month with 0.

with this config logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd} result is => logstash-2021.01.**01-000001**

with this config logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.d} result is => logstash-2021.01.**1**

```
input {
   redis {
       host => "someip_of_redis"
       data_type => "list"
       key => "logstash"
       codec => "json"
   }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["http://someip_of_elastic:9200"]
       index => "logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: And which part do you find strange? The `-000001`?

Comment: yes, -000001, i do not need this

Comment: Yes, but that's standard. It's how Elasticsearch deals with index rollover (which is a separate mechanism). Ignore it, it does not have any negative consequences for you.

Comment: is it new now? in 5.x, 6.x version it was without -000001. thx

Answer (score 2):

to disable it, i add to config following ilm_enabled => false

```
input {
   redis {
       host => "someip_of_redis"
       data_type => "list"
       key => "logstash"
       codec => "json"
   }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["http://someip_of_elastic:9200"]
       ilm_enabled => false
       index => "logstash-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know. :)